# Compiliation error with templates using g++, compiles ok with llvm

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, g++

I really don't know what to make of this.  I have some code that is being shared on iOS and a Linux server.  The iOS LLVM compiler compiles just fine however when I try to compile on Linux with g++ I get many errors.  The first one being the following:

```
RemoveLight.h: In member function ‘void RemoveLight<WindowDerived, ChunkDerived, dim>::lightRemoveEditStart()’:
RemoveLight.h:49:17: error: ‘FloodFillLight’ was not declared in this scope
RemoveLight.h:49:45: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
RemoveLight.h:49:59: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
```

This is line 49:

```
FloodFillLight<WindowDerived, ChunkDerived, dim>(x, i, z, target, chunkWindow);
```

I do have FloodFillLight.h included in RemoveLight.h so that isn't the problem and my templates are all declared in a .h file.  I don't have any part of the templates defined in a cpp file.  Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try preprocessing the file and make sure that FloodFillLight is declared before it's used.

It might be that a stray #ifdef is muddling up your includes.